# modify or create cite commands like \citet{} or \citep{} that show day, month, and year in-line

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

I'm writing a document that cites emails, and I'm trying to use a .bib file to manage the emails that I cite.

How can I modify the cite commands `\citet{Smith:2023aa}` or `\citep{Smith:2023aa}`, or how can I create a custom cite command, to produce in-line citations that appear as "Smith (February 28, 2023)" or "(Smith, February 28, 2023)" in my document?

I am not picky about the specific formatting of the date shown in the document, so long as day, month, and year are shown in-line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Smith:2020aa,
    title = {Subject: Minimum Working Example}
    author = {John Smith},
    date = {2020-02-28}
  }
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[
      style=apa,
      labeldate=comp, 
      dateabbrev= false,
      natbib,
      backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{Smith:2020aa}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your advice on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created `\citewithdatep`, that prints (Author, Month Day, Year), and `\citewithdatet`, that prints Author (Month Day, Year):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Smith:2020aa,
    title = {Subject: Minimum Working Example},
    author = {John Smith},
    date = {2020-02-28}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    labeldate=comp, 
    dateabbrev= false,
    natbib,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citewithdatep}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}% 
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\mkbibparens{%
      \printnames{labelname}% 
      \addcomma\addspace%
      \printfield{month}%
      \addspace%
      \printfield{day}%
      \addcomma\addspace%
      \printfield{year}%
      }%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citewithdatet}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}% 
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\printnames{labelname}% 
   \addspace%
   \mkbibparens{%
      \printfield{month}%
      \addspace%
      \printfield{day}%
      \addcomma\addspace%
      \printfield{year}%
      }%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}  
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is an email citation in the format (Author, Month Day, Year):

\citewithdatep{Smith:2020aa}

This is an email citation in the format Author (Month Day, Year):

\citewithdatet{Smith:2020aa}

This is an ordinary citation
\citet{Smith:2020aa}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Comment: @RMM You're welcome, and thank you for accepting my answer.